# hierarchical compile order with modelsim on command line

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

I'm trying to compile a VHDL design with modelsim on command line. Is there any way to get an automatical compile order according to the design hierarchy?

I didn't find an option in the documentation of `vcom`. Only link I found is [this](https://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/modelsim-vcom-dependency-order.23442/), where the solution was to write a brute force script. But it's 10 years ago, so maybe there is anything new. It should be like the option `-i` of `ghdl`.

I'm using Altera/Intel Modelsim 18.0 on Linux.

Comment: ghdl -i (import) imports specified VHDL files into the working library without analysis. ghdl -m *configuration_or_entity_target* (make) analyzes them in the correct order and elaborates the passed design unit name. ghdl also has an internal makefile generator (--gen-makefile) that outputs the text for a makefile, with  import ordered dependencies for elaborating a target. ghdl --gen-depends will output file dependency without the complete makefile text. See [Invoking GHDL](https://ghdl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/InvokingGHDL.html).

Comment: You are right. I confused -i with -m. If there isn't an option to get the dependencies directly via vcom command, I will try to use the workaround with ghdl --gen-depends.

Comment: Take a look at this [ModelSim Compile Script](https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/tcltk/examples/modelsim/). I didn't try it but it might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[VUnit](http://vunit.github.io) is an open source tool that will that for you. I recommend the following reading

1. [Installation](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/vunit-best-value-initial-effort-lars-asplund/)
2. [Compilation](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/vunit-best-value-initial-effort-part-2-lars-asplund/) (what you're looking for)

Disclaimer: I'm one of the authors

Comment: Actually I wrote my full testbench in Python (Cocotb), since I need some Python functionality. I'm not sure if VUnit + VHDL testbench can provide the same functionality, but I will take a look.

Comment: Depends on how you use Python but you can use VUnit integer_array_t to get data in and out of your simulation and then create Python hooks to produce/consume that data. https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/vunit-matlab-integration-lars-asplund/ can serve as inspiration.

Comment: It looks well to me. I just don't know when I will have the time to rewrite my testbench and test it. I will let you know.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that in recent versions (tested in ModelSim SE-64 2020.4), `vcom` supports a new `-autoorder` parameter, which is described as follows:

> Source files can be specified in any order. When all source files can
> be specified on a single command line, compilation proceeds in a scan
> phase, followed by a refresh phase. To perform the scan phase over
> multiple compilations, inhibit the refresh phase with
> -noautoorderrefresh. Then perform the refresh phase with -refresh_marked (and omit -autoorder).

Just by adding the `-autoorder` parameter, I was able to easily compile a large VHDL project with many dependencies, that previously failed due to wrong compile order.